# How to use ssl in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, https

I am using python 2.7 and i need secure url with ssl protocol(HTTPS).Can we do this in python 2.7
when i trying to import ssl i m getting the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in 
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: symbol SSLeay_version, version OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference.

Please help me if anybody know...Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install Python?

Comment: I m using Linux fedora19, I installed as "yum install python"

Comment: Check to make sure that you have OpenSSL 1.0.1 installed on your box

Comment: Yah OpenSSL is installed...

Answer (score 0):

I got Answer

I have re-installed openssl

This is the code i used in terminal

sudo yum install openssl-devel